# Get user from parse in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I know this question may be asked multiple times but I am not able to get the User object in its entirity. The problem is that the user object returns only the username, email and the phone number properties while I have certain fields added like first name and last name to the user object.

I'd like to know if there's a way to get the user object in its entirity

The object on parse cloud should look like

```
User: 
{
    "firstname": "firstname",
    "lastname": "lastname",
    "username": "username",
    "email": "abc.xyz@jkl.pqr",
    "phone": "0123456789",
    "type": "admin/super-admin/user"
}
```

I use following query to get the object

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", "username"); // Whatever be the username passed by search string
query.find({
    success: function (user) {
        console.log("Success:", user)

    },
    error: function (error) {
        //Show if no user was found to match
    }
});
```

I get the user object as follows:

```
user:{
    createdAt:"2014-12-27T07:16:09.826Z"
    email: "abc.xyz@pqr.mno"
    objectId: "223tch5S6J"
    phone: "0123456789"
    updatedAt: "2014-12-27T07:16:09.826Z"
    username: "username"
}
```

I do not get the other properties like type, firstname, lastname.

**Note: I do not need to get the password which parse does not provide anyways so that's not the problem here.**

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you sure that the object on the cloud looks like that? I noticed you are using the phrase 'should look' and I also noticed that the email in the result differs from the email you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user.attributes` should hold all the user attributes saved server side